# How to increase the size of a subplot figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to create a summary figure that consists of multiple subplots. The issue is that I can not increase the overall size of the figure past the size of the screen. I am trying to create a 12 by 8 subplot so I can view all the figures from an experiment at the same time. However when I generate the subplot this is the result I receive.

[Example subplot figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRU4A.png)

And here is the code I used to generate said figure.

```
c = {'r' 'c' 'g' 'm' 'y' 'k'};
    for x = 1:96
        table = load(file_array(x).name);
        table = struct2array(table);
        [~,col] = size(table);
        subplot_tight(12,8,x);
        for t = 1:col
            plot(table(:,t), c{t});
            hold on
        end
        H = sprintf('%s\n', file_array(x).name);
        title(H);

    end
    figname = sprintf('%s_Duration_part1',heading.name(1:end-4));

    saveas(gcf, figname, 'fig');

    close all  %reset figure
```

It's nice that all the sub-figures are visible but it is essentially impossible to actually read the data from the subplots. What would be ideal is to save it so the entire figure is bigger so I can scroll through a bigger figure and look at the sub-figures. Or alternatively if there is a way to save a stack of figures as a slideshow. Ultimately so that all the data for a specific experiment is organized in one respective figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the whole figure, don't look at the figure itself, but use the [`print`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) function to configure the renderer.

Try something like:

```
print('-r1200','Plot','-dpng',)
```

This sets the `DPI` setting higher, so you should have more information displayed. You can change some other properties to play with the aspect ratio, the [renderer size](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102382-how-do-i-specify-the-output-sizes-of-jpeg-png-and-tiff-images-when-using-the-print-function-in-mat), etc.

Unfortunately I only have access to octave right now, so I can't really provide you with a working example.

Comment: Using print did give alot more control over the final resolution. This bit of code worked for me pretty well.    `set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 80 45])
        print('-dtiff', figname, '-r100')`